# Check boxes issue in Dynamics CRM Portal

Tags: jquery, dynamics-crm-portals

Upon clicking a button I want to display checkboxes in the view I am displaying in my portal.I have added them by using below lines but if I click on the same button twice or thrice another column of checkboxes are getting added. how can I avoid that? Also I want to select single check box at a time but my checkboxes are not unique now, I want to make them unique.When user selects more than one check-box I want to show a pop-up like you can only select a single check-box at a time.

```
$('tr[data-entity="ess_asset"]').each(function() {
  $(this).children(':last-child').after('<td id="checkbox1"><input type="checkbox" /></td>');
});
```

Comment: `using below lines` which one ?

Comment: $('tr[data-entity="ess_asset"]').each(function () {
    $(this).children(':last-child').after('<td id="checkbox1"><input type="checkbox" /></td>');
    });

Comment: @yashu Please use the edit button if you need to add more content to your question, don't paste it into the comment section.

Comment: First of all, when you run that code, all of the `td` that you insert will have the same ID and that is a big no no, Ids should always be unique.